# OpenCV Max locations

Tags: opencv

I am working on an OpenCV project and am using cvMatchTemplate to locate part of an image I am then using cvMinMaxLoc to find the maximum area, therefore best match, my problem is that cvMinMaxLoc only returns one max location were as there may be multiple matches in one image.

Is there any way to return all the max locations above a particular threshold

I.e.

for each location > threshold
add location to array

I'm new to OpenCV and dont know if something like this already exists but so far I haven't been able to find anything

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I modified the `matchTemplate` tutorial to get you started. It basically uses a `queue` to track the top X match points, and later plots all of them. Hope that is helpful!

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <queue>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void maxLocs(const Mat& src, queue<Point>& dst, size_t size)
{
    float maxValue = -1.0f * numeric_limits<float>::max();
    float* srcData = reinterpret_cast<float*>(src.data);

    for(int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
        {
            if(srcData[i*src.cols + j] > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = srcData[i*src.cols + j];

                dst.push(Point(j, i));

                // pop the smaller one off the end if we reach the size threshold.
                if(dst.size() > size)
                {
                    dst.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Global Variables
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;
string image_window = "Source Image";
string result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /// Load image and template
    img = imread( "dogs.jpg", 1 );
    templ = imread( "dog_templ.jpg", 1 );

    /// Create windows
    namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    /// Create Trackbar
    string trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
    createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

    MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}

/**
 * @function MatchingMethod
 * @brief Trackbar callback
 */
void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
    /// Source image to display
    Mat img_display;
    img.copyTo( img_display );

    /// Create the result matrix
    int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

    result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );

    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
    normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
    if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    {
        result = 1.0 - result;
    }

    // get the top 100 maximums...
    queue<Point> locations;
    maxLocs(result, locations, 100);

    /// Show me what you got
    while(!locations.empty())
    {
        Point matchLoc = locations.front();
        rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
        rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
        locations.pop();
    }

    imshow( image_window, img_display );
    imshow( result_window, result );

    return;
}
```

Comment: Max and min values are within spots (rounded areas) where need to find single max or min value and, then, drop processed spot and start looking within another spot which is much pixels away from all **local** max or min values within processed spot. It's like measure mountains: if first one 10 meters taller than another then you don't say that first occupies first 10 places as "tallest mountain" and 11'th place is for second one. But presented algorythm will say that. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This was just a quick example to show how to get multiple maximum matches. However, if you need a local maxima finding algorithm, I can add that to the answer as well...

Comment: That would be great, but the complication is allocating such spots and just then find within them.

Comment: Your code stops finding maxima as soon as the maximum value is reached. For instance, if the maximum value is located at the very beginning of the matrix, then no other maxima will be found. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try cvThreshold(src, dst, threshold, CV_THRESH_BINARY)

This would return an image in dst with all pixels above threshold as white and all others as black. You would then iterate through all the pixels and check if it is greater than 0 then that is a location you want. Something like this

```
   char* data = dst->imageData;
   int size = (dst->height) * (dst->width)

   for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
       if(data[i] > 0)
          //copy i into your array
   }
```

Comment: The issue I had with this is, there will be a small cluster of pixels, not just a single pixel at the location where a match is found