# Object Detection using cvtemplatematch

Tags: opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV Max locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156405/opencv-max-locations)

I used opencv's cvtemplatematch for object detection . It detects only one match for any object. Can anyone tell me how to create a loop to find all the possible matches in an image if there's more than one match?

Answer (score 0):

the function MatchTemplate creates a probability map, where pixel values represent the probability that there is the searced object. What you have to do is to access the result of Matchtemplate, and instead taking the maximum value, look for all the values above a certain threshold.

To use the correct threshold is up to you - is application-dependent. But for a simple check it would be enough to, let's say, find the max, and then, all the peaks above 70% of max.