# Finding all matches with matchtemplate opencv opencvsharp

Tags: .net, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv with opencvsharp.

When doing a matchtemplate and afterwards minmaxloc I only get the first match. How do I get all matches?

```
            Cv.MatchTemplate(tempImg, templateSymbol.Img, resImg, MatchTemplateMethod.CCorrNormed);
            double min_val, max_val;
            Cv.MinMaxLoc(resImg, out min_val, out max_val);
            if (max_val > 0.5)
            {

                symbolsFound.Add(templateSymbol.Description);
                Console.WriteLine(templateSymbol.Description);
            }
```

I only find the first match and I know there are more matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162277/951860) where I show how to do exactly what you are asking for. It is written in C++, but should be fairly trivial to port to C#. Instead of using a `std::queue` use a .NET [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx).

Essentially, you need to scan across your `resImg` looking for all of the maximum (or minimum depending on the comparison algorithm) points, and record as many as you want into some kind of container (list, queue, priority queue, etc...). `MinMaxLoc` will only return the top match, so that is why you are only getting one match.

Answer (score 4):

```
try
        {

            IplImage tpl = Cv.LoadImage("template path", LoadMode.Color);
            IplImage img = Cv.LoadImage("main image path", LoadMode.Color);

            IplImage res = Cv.CreateImage(Cv.Size(img.Width - tpl.Width + 1, img.Height - tpl.Height + 1), BitDepth.F32, 1);
            Cv.MatchTemplate(img, tpl, res, MatchTemplateMethod.CCoeffNormed);

            Cv.Threshold(res, res, 0.9, 255, ThresholdType.ToZero);

            while (true)
            {
                CvPoint minloc, maxloc;
                double minval, maxval, threshold = 0.95;

                Cv.MinMaxLoc(res, out minval, out maxval, out minloc, out maxloc, null);
                if (maxval > threshold)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Matched " + maxloc.X + "," + maxloc.Y);
                    Cv.FloodFill(res, maxloc, new CvScalar());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No More Matches");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Cv.ReleaseImage(res);
            Cv.ReleaseImage(img);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```